# steam api спарсить инвентарь

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api

Пытаюсь спарсить инвентарь с помощью api https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/ID/730/2?count=1000, но получаю только 30 предметов, дальше затрудняюсь. Пытался добавлять start_assetid=0, но когда изменяю значение, не получаю ничего. Буду благодарен за помощь!

пример полученного ответа json:

```
    assets  […]
descriptions    
0   {…}
1   {…}
2   {…}
3   {…}
4   {…}
5   {…}
6   {…}
7   {…}
8   {…}
9   {…}
10  {…}
11  {…}
12  {…}
13  {…}
14  {…}
15  {…}
16  {…}
17  {…}
18  {…}
19  {…}
20  {…}
21  {…}
22  {…}
23  {…}
24  {…}
25  {…}
26  {…}
27  {…}
28  {…}
29  {…}
total_inventory_count   391
success 1
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример вывода ответа

Comment: @Exord да, в json ответе приходит только 30 предметов

Comment: Странно, я получаю все. попробуйте добавить ?l=english&count=5000 

https://imgur.com/nD05O1q.png

Comment: даже l не влияет на самом деле. И без него тоже всё получается  https://imgur.com/fAxIYwl.png

Comment: Через что вы совершаете запрос? из кода, браузера или из REST клиента? Попробуйте в другом месте совершить запрос. У меня предположение, что приложение в котором вы делаете запрос, почему то срезает вывод

Comment: @Exord делаю запрос как в коде, так и через браузер, результат одинаковый

Comment: а внутри объектов, обычные итемы? там не появилось случаем вложенности дополнительной? И ещё, сколько элементов вам приходит в assets ?

Comment: @Exord в assets приходит 390, то есть столько сколько и должно, видимо я не совсем понимаю как нужно было перебирать полученный ответ, ведь я перебираю descriptions, но в assets не знаю какое поле нужно для определения

Comment: Следовательно вы получаете 390 предметов. Но описаний приходит только 30. Не может ли быть тут такой ситуации. Что у вас много одинаковых предметов? и стим не отсылает повторно к тому же итему описание? Я бы попробовал сравнить вывод описаний, и ассетов

Comment: @Exord да, вы правы, осталось только разобраться как получить информацию о предмете из assets

Comment: Предложил ответ на python. Ознакомьтесь и попробуйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример на **python**. Как связать assets и описание к ним.

```
import requests

test_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198061078208/440/2?count=5000'

r = requests.get(test_url)

match r.status_code:
    case 200:
        items = []
        r_obj = r.json()
        for asset in r_obj['assets']:
            for description in r_obj['descriptions']:
                if asset['classid'] == description['classid']:
                    items.append({'item': asset['classid'], 'description': description, 'asset': asset})
                    break
        print(items)
    case 429:
        print('Слишком много запросов. Сюда можно вставить любой обработчик.')
    case _:
        print('Любые другие случаи.')
```